# Connect multiple containers, nginx and php through fastcgi

Tags: docker-compose

I have three containers, mysql, phpfpm and nginx.

When I try to run the localhost:8080 I get this error:

```
[error] 11#11: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.27.0.1, server: _,.
request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.27.0.3:9000", host: "localhost:8080"
```

Can anybody help me with this? What do I miss?

Here is my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    build: php
    container_name: phpfpm
    expose:
      - '9002'
      - '9000'
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - /srv/www/mito/app:/var/www/html
      - ./dockerlive/logs:/var/log
    command: /bin/bash -c "rm -rf /var/run/php && mkdir /var/run/php && rm -rf /run/php && mkdir /run/php && /usr/sbin/php-fpm7.4 -F -R"
  nginx:
    build: nginx
    container_name: webserver
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    depends_on:
      - php
      - db
    volumes:
      - /srv/www/mito/app:/var/www/html
      - ./dockerlive/logs:/var/log/nginx
    environment:
      - NGINX_HOST=localhost
      - NGINX_PORT=80
    command: /bin/bash -c "nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
  db:
    build: database
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mito
```

and the nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name _;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.php;

    #error_log /var/log/nginx/mito.localhost-error.log;
    #access_log /var/log/nginx/mito.localhost-acces.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass    phpfpm:9000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found somewhere a useful idea what I've implemented.

I've added an entry to the nginx and the php volumes:

```
- php-fpm-socket:/var/run/php
```

and I've also defined it in the main volumes section without any parameter.